# PowerShell FFMPEG Image Extraction direct to System Drawing Image

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, stream, screen, screenshot

I've been racking my brain for the last 48 hours... I rarely ask a question, but I'm at my breaking point. Hopefully the experts can help.

**Problem:** I need to extract an image from a video (not save the file) and allow me to manipulate it with PowerShell's System Drawing package.

```
$ffmpeg = "C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
$input = "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\test.mp4"
$screenshot = & $ffmpeg -i $input -ss 3 -vframes 1 -c:v bmp -f image2pipe -


##Not having issues with getting FFMPEG to pipe to a variable
##The output looks to be UTF8, but I can't convert it to a memory stream for System Drawing
##All examples I've found are using a file written to disk...I don't want to write a file


##Issues start here:
$enc = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$utf_screenshot = $enc.GetBytes($screenshot)
$base64_screenshot = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($utf_screenshot)
$ms = new-object System.IO.MemoryStream($base64_screenshot)
$img = [system.drawing.Image]::FromStream($ms)
```

I'm not very savvy with file encoding...

Any help would be appreciated - thank you!

Comment: You're converting the bytes to a base64 string and try to add it to a memorystream (which doesn't take a string aa argument). I'm not really familiar with the output of ffmpeg, but my guess is that you get a base64 string from the application. Just convert that base64 string to a byte array and feed it to the memorystream

Comment: Don't think I'm getting base64 from output.... output looks like this from FFMPEG:



<br>
BMöP      6   (   ”  Ð        ÀP                  jh_ljapnetritriqofomdjh_feZlkqpeqpeqof][R[YPljakpiTYRRXS_ebjg[cO[XR^[[gfiu
`

Comment: Ok, in that case: just try to convert this to bytes (I'd try ASCII first) and feed the byte array to the streamreader instead of converting it to base64

Comment: WIth:
---------------------
$enc = [system.Text.Encoding]::ASCII
$ascii_screenshot = $enc.GetBytes($screenshot)
---------------------
I get the error: "new-object : Cannot find an overload for "MemoryStream" and the argument count: "872154"..........when I try and do that

Answer (score 2):

I Finally Figured it out.... Here is the answer:

```
$ffmpeg = "C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
$input = "C:\test.mp4"
$image = & $ffmpeg -i $input -ss 3 -vframes 1 -c:v bmp -f image2pipe -



$bytes = [system.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes($image)
$stream = new-object System.IO.MemoryStream(,$bytes)
$image = [system.drawing.Image]::FromStream($stream)


write-host $image.Height
write-host $image.Width
```